# What is the norm of this bounded linear operator?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, linear-transformations, normed-spaces

Let $a$ and $b$ be two real numbers such that $a < b$; let $\mathrm{C}[a, b]$ denote the normed space of all the (real or) complex-valued functions defined and continuous on the closed interval $[a, b]$ on the real line, with the maximum norm.

For each $x \in \mathrm{C}[a, b]$, let us define the function $\tilde{x}$ on $[a, b]$ as follows: $$ \tilde{x}(t) \colon= \int_a^t x(\tau) \ \mathrm{d} \tau \mbox{ for each } \tau \in [a, b]. $$ 
By Theorem 6.20 in Baby Rudin, 3rd edition, each $\tilde{x}$ is continuous (in fact, even differentiable) on $[a, b]$.

Am I right?

This defines a mapping $f \colon \mathrm{C}[a, b] \to \mathrm{C}[a, b]$, $x \mapsto \tilde{x}$,  which is linear and bounded.

What is the norm of $f$?

My Attempt:

> For every $x \in \mathrm{C}[a, b]$, we have 
>   $$ \lvert \tilde{x} (t) \rvert = \left\lvert \int_a^t x(\tau)  \ \mathrm{d} \tau   \right\rvert \leq \int_a^t \left\lvert  x(\tau) \right\rvert 
>   \ \mathrm{d} \tau \leq \int_a^t \lVert x \rVert \ \mathrm{d} \tau = (t-a) \lVert x \rVert \leq (b-a) \lVert x \rVert. $$
>   and so 
>   $$ \lVert \tilde{x} \rVert = \max \{ \ \lvert \tilde{x}(t) \rvert \ \colon \ t \in [a, b] \ \} \leq (b-a) \lVert x \rVert, $$
>   which shoows that $f$ is indeed bounded, and upon taking the supremum over all $x$ of unit norm, we obtain $$ \lVert f \rVert \leq  b-a. $$
>
> Now for $x$ defined as $x(t) \colon= 1$ for all $t \in [a, b]$, we find that $\lVert x \rVert = 1$ and also that 
>   $$ \tilde{x}(t) = \int_a^t x(\tau) \ \mathrm{d} \tau = t-a, $$
>   and so $\lVert \tilde{x} \rVert = b-a$, from which it follows that $$ \lVert f \rVert \geq b-a. $$
>   Hence $\lVert f \rVert = b-a$.

Is what I have done so far correct? If not, then where lies the error?

Comment: @user284331 what have you edited in my post?

Comment: No, you just had a typo, $\displaystyle\int |x(\tau) d\tau$ and I removed the $|$.

Comment: I know this is an old post, but I found it useful. Can you clarify what Theorem 6.2 is?

Comment: @JosephDasenbrock here is Theorem 6.20 in the book _Principles of Mathematical Analysis_ by Walter Rudin, 3rd edition: Let $f$ be a real-valued, Riemann-integrable function on $[a, b]$, and for each $x \in [a, b]$, let us put $$F(x) = \int_a^x f(t) dt. $$ Then $F$ is continuous on $[a, b]$; furthermore, if $f$ is continuous at a point $x_0$ of $[a, b]$, then $F$ is differentiable at $x_0$ and $$F^\prime\left(x_0\right) = f\left( x_0 \right). $$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your attempt is fine, everything is O.K., no errors !